# How can I move an object from one javascript file to another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm basically trying to pass an object from app.js to server.js.

I've looked at all of the similar questions to moving variables from one file to another, but I can't seem to implement those solutions into my situation.

I've got 2 javascript files and 1 html file. In the first javascript file, I'm fetching data from app.js which goes into the variable data:

```js
$(function() {
 $.getJSON('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
sessionStorage.setItem('mydata', data);
});
```

In the server.js file, I'm trying to retrieve the variable called data and console log it.  I feel like I'm close because I get [object object], but can't seem to get that to open up to the data set.

```js
var newData = sessionStorage.getItem('mydata');
console.log("From server.js:", newData);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="server.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I also have this example at plunker if that's easier to see:http://plnkr.co/edit/kqwvW545sDKDMr0kidcd

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are saving an object directly into the session storage.
you should save it as a JSON string. In session storage you should not save an object directly.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('mydata', JSON.stringify(data));
```

you can retrieve the object and JSON.parse it in the server.js

```
var newData = sessionStorage.getItem('mydata');
console.log("From server.js:", JSON.parse(newData));
```

in app.js make the following change in your plunker code so that the data in session storage is stored and server.js is loaded once the ajax call is finished.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow', function(data) {
    console.log("resp",data);
     sessionStorage.setItem('mydata', JSON.stringify(data));


    $.getScript( "server.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    });
  })


});
```

in server.js

```
var newData = sessionStorage.getItem('mydata');
console.log("From server.js:", JSON.parse(newData));
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bEXEBZxPByjErmMTNblf?p=preview